# Printing data to list styled (table) from XML in Python

Tags: python, xml, list, tabular

I'd like to print my servers as listed. Like this:

```
Machine  | Group               | IP            | Services
- Alpha  | Public Server Group | 192.168.1.251 | JBoss, Tomcat
- Public | Public Server Group | 192.168.1.253 | JBoss, Tomcat
```

My XML is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<AllConfigurations>

<DeployConfigurations>

    <Servers>

        <Group id="1" name="Public Server Group" username="root" password="mypasswd123" state="">
            <GApp id="1" name="JBoss Servers" type="JBoss" path="/root/Desktop/jboss-as-7.0.2.Final/" state="">
                <Server id="1" name="Alpha" ip="192.168.1.251" path="/root/Desktop/jboss-as-7.0.2.Final/" username="" password="" state="" />
                <Server id="2" name="Public" ip="192.168.1.253" path="/root/Desktop/jboss-as-7.0.2.Final/" username="" password="" state="" />
            </GApp>
            <GApp id="2" name="Tomcat Servers" type="Tomcat" path="/root/Desktop/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/" state="">
                <Server id="1" name="Alpha" ip="192.168.1.251" path="/root/Desktop/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/" username="" password="" state="" />
                <Server id="2" name="Public" ip="192.168.1.253" path="/root/Desktop/apache-tomcat-7.0.22/" username="" password="" state="" />
            </GApp>
        </Group>

    </Servers>

</DeployConfigurations>

</AllConfigurations>
```

I'm trying to do by this:

```
from xml.dom.minidom import parse

yXML = parse('/root/Desktop/gb/data/yConfig.xml')

print (' ')
print ('Machine       |       Group       |       IP       |       Services')

for AllConfigurations in yXML.getElementsByTagName('AllConfigurations'):
    for DeployConfigurations in AllConfigurations.getElementsByTagName('DeployConfigurations'):
        for Servers in DeployConfigurations.getElementsByTagName('Servers'):
            for Group in Servers.getElementsByTagName('Group'):
                for GApp in Group.getElementsByTagName('GApp'):
                    for Server in Group.getElementsByTagName('Server'):

                        print Server.getAttribute('name') + ' | ' + Group.getAttribute('name') + ' | ' + Server.getAttribute('ip') + ' | ' + GApp.getAttribute('type')
```

My result is:

```
Machine  | Group               | IP            | Services
Alpha | Public Server Group | 192.168.1.251 | JBoss
Public | Public Server Group | 192.168.1.253 | JBoss
Alpha | Public Server Group | 192.168.1.251 | JBoss
Public | Public Server Group | 192.168.1.253 | JBoss
Alpha | Public Server Group | 192.168.1.251 | Tomcat
Public | Public Server Group | 192.168.1.253 | Tomcat
Alpha | Public Server Group | 192.168.1.251 | Tomcat
Public | Public Server Group | 192.168.1.253 | Tomcat
```

What should I do?

Its printing for every possibility. I can't align Services side-by-side, print for one IP and look like table.

Need help..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, you cannot print the lines right away; rather store the data (as tuples) in a list (`servers`). To group the services by machine / group / IP, you can use the `itertools` function `groupby`, specifying the first three fields as key tuple. (Before that, the list has to be sorted so `groupby` finds all duplicates.) `groupby` yields the key (3-tuple) and a generator for the rest of corresponding lines; here, we're interested in the unique values of the fourth value (the service), so we convert the values to a `set` and join them by spaces.

The issue with aligning the table can be solved by using the `string` function `ljust` (left justify). I made a separate function to generalize the rendering of the header line and the data rows.

Here's the code:

```
from itertools import groupby

servers = []
for AllConfigurations in yXML.getElementsByTagName('AllConfigurations'):
    for DeployConfigurations in AllConfigurations.getElementsByTagName('DeployConfigurations'):
        for Servers in DeployConfigurations.getElementsByTagName('Servers'):
            for Group in Servers.getElementsByTagName('Group'):
                for GApp in Group.getElementsByTagName('GApp'):
                    for Server in Group.getElementsByTagName('Server'):
                        servers.append((Server.getAttribute('name'),
                                Group.getAttribute('name'),
                                Server.getAttribute('ip'),
                                GApp.getAttribute('type')))

def line(machine, group, ip, services):
    return " | ".join([machine.ljust(8), group.ljust(20), ip.ljust(15), services])

print line("Machine", "Group", "IP", "Services")
for server, services in groupby(sorted(servers), lambda server: server[0:3]):
    print line("- " + server[0], server[1], server[2],
            ", ".join(service[3] for service in set(services)))
```

This prints

```
Machine  | Group                | IP              | Services
- Alpha  | Public Server Group  | 192.168.1.251   | JBoss, Tomcat
- Public | Public Server Group  | 192.168.1.253   | Tomcat, JBoss
```

Comment: Its great but I'm having this error: `  File "/root/Desktop/gb/data/ListServers.py", line 27
    def line(machine, group, ip, services):
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: sorry, apparently there was a `)` missing in the line before

Comment: I miss that too. Thanks for solving my problem!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to take advantage of the [format specification mini-language](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language) available in python:

```
data = ('Machine', 'Group', 'IP', 'Services')
# left aligned (default)                                                                                                                  
print '{0:20} | {1:20} | {2:20} | {3:20}'.format(*data)
# rigth aligned (default)                                                                                                                 
print '{0:>20} | {1:>20} | {2:>20} | {3:>20}'.format(*data)
# centered                                                                                                                                
print '{0:^20} | {1:^20} | {2:^20} | {3:^20}'.format(*data)
```

The output of the script above is:

```
Machine              | Group                | IP                   | Services
             Machine |                Group |                   IP |             Services
      Machine        |        Group         |          IP          |       Services
```